# turn large navigation into a drop down for mobile devices

Tags: mobile, navigation, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive website at the moment and the main site navigation contains 10 links. I've seen a few sites that compress their navigation into a simple drop down select menu when the screen size gets below 480px, but I can't find any tutorials out there that explain how to do this - apart from the CSS Tricks one here:

http://www.css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/

I've tried this tutorial but not had any success with it as I implemented the code and yes I get a lovely menu on the iPhone, but the links don't work and clicking on it makes the page zoom in which is not desirable as this doesn't happen when I don't have the menu in place.

I'm looking for something simple like used on these websites:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/

http://www.lancs.ac.uk/

anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find this snippet of code on http://www.w3schools.com here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_selectmenu

Implemented it and it works just fine - just had to add action="" to the form tag to get the page to validate.